# Using Hooks for fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use hooks to fetch data from an endpoint and I keep getting an error saying

**Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.**
**Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function**

I have tried fetching data without hooks and it works fine.

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const fetchData = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('someendpoint');
            const jsonResponse = await response.json();
            setData(jsonResponse);
        }

        getData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div></div>
    )
}       

export default fetchData;
```

Comment: `fetchData` should probably be `FetchData` since it's a component. that might be it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the component to a valid name: `FetchData` with a capital letter to pass the linter check (matches inside capitalized function name scope a function with `use` prefix).

See [User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string `'div'` or `'span'` passed to `React.createElement`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem it still throws the same error.

Comment: So please create a reproducible example in codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-gyep7?file=/index.js

Comment: If you can't reproduce, there is no problem, you may be overlooking another bug that is not related **on your machine**.